# -ng sound in idiosyncratic

Tags: pronunciation

The pronunciation of **idiosyncratic** as given by OALD on [their website](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/idiosyncratic?q=idiosyncratic) is: /ˌɪdiəsɪŋˈkrætɪk/

Why is there an -ng sound in the pronunciation?

Comment: I don't hear any -ng sounds in the audio samples provided.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey I, too, didn't hear the -ng sound in the audio sample but it is there in the transcription (is that the word?) in the form of /ŋ/. That is what puzzled me?

Comment: It could be an error, OALD is not immune. I certainly don't say 'idiosyngcratic', and neither do the speakers in the audio samples. [Dictionary.com](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/idiosyncratic) gives ˌ`ɪd i oʊ sɪnˈkræt ɪk` as an IPA transcription which is more in line with my experience.

Comment: I hear [ŋ]. in the British, but [n] in the American, however I think this is within normal variation and isn't phonemic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not uncommon in English for the letter N to represent the sound [ŋ] before a [k] sound, but this is subject to some variation. When both sounds occur together in the same syllable, the sequence [nk] does not occur: we always find [ŋ] in words such as *sink,* *Sphinx,* or *sphincter.* When the [k] occurs at the start of a new syllable, [nk] and [ŋk] are both possible, but even though these are distinguishable sound sequences, the difference is not very large.

Here is a paper discussing some of the situations where [n] vs. [ŋ] occurs in prefixed words: "[Velar POA assimilation in Latinate prefixation in contemporary English: A study in the Beats-and-Binding Phonology](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/303311610_Velar_POA_assimilation_in_Latinate_prefixation_in_contemporary_English_A_study_in_the_Beats-and-Binding_Phonology)", Małgorzata Haładewicz-Grzelak, January 2015. (Etymologically, the *-syn-* in *idiosyncratic* is from a Greek prefix, although I don't know how relevant that etymology is.) The patterns about when we find one pronunciation vs. the other are pretty complicated (things like stress and which prefix is involved can potentially play a role), and there isn't agreement between speakers for all cases.

I would say it does not matter much which one you use in this word. [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/idiosyncratic) gives "ˌi-​dē-​ō-​(ˌ)sin-​ˈkra-​tik". [Dictionary.com](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/idiosyncratic) lists both as options: "/ ˌɪd i oʊ sɪnˈkræt ɪk, -sɪŋ- /".

Answer (score 1):

I hear [ŋ] in the British.  The presence of the velar consonant /k/ will tend to affect the /n/ that precedes it causing it to become [ŋ] or a blend [nŋ].  This is similar to how a biblical consonant can cause an "n" to become an "m" in words like "impossible" (from in- and possible).

However I don't think this is a phonemic change.  If the sound was purely [n] the word would not be any different in how it was understood. In fact I'd have to listen far more carefully than normal to even notice any difference.

Comment: I am British and I say the 'syn' part of ideosyncratic exactly like I would say 'sin' if I am speaking carefully.

Comment: I'm fairyly sure that I say it like I would say "sing", especially if I'm speaking quickly.  But introspection on pronunciation isn't always easy.